# Substituent effect on Aromatic compound (Nucleophilic addition)

Tags: aromatic-compounds

The reaction shows a nucleophilic addition:

[image]

The reaction on the left is faster because methoxy substituent is on the meta position of the ring, while the right side reaction is located on the para position of the ring. What difference does the 2 different positions come into play here? The -OMe substituent is electron donating and in both cases will donate electrons to the ring. Why is then the left handed reaction preferred or faster?

Comment: Left reaction has predominantly inductive effect, which increases the electrophilic nature of carbonyl carbon. Right reaction dominated by mesomeric effect, which reduces the electrophilic nature of carbonyl carbon.

Comment: Deaw a resonance structure with $\ce{C+ - O-}$ at the carbonyl group. Then see where additional resonance structures can delocalize the positive charge from the carbonyl carbon. Which molecule ends up with more delocalization and thus weaker positive charge on the carbonyl carbon?